# Firebird update or insert primary key violation

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I try to update or insert into a Firebird database table.

But after a new entry, the next time I try to update I get a PK violation.

Both times I use:

```
 UPDATE OR INSERT INTO NAMES ( ID, NAME , SURENAME ) VALUES ( 123, 'Peter', 'Miller'  ) matching (Name)
```

But each time with different surnames.

The ID is a PK in the table. And I generate the ID at the first time.

Comment: Please show the relevant DDL of the table and the trigger for generating the primary key. You are including the ID, and depending on how the trigger is set up you may not actually be generating a new id, but just using this one.

Comment: Maybe you run your insert from different transactions (different connections) and you did not committed the first tx before starting the 2nd tx ?